# how to hide the numbering of \fakesection{} from the Table of content

Tags: sectioning

I have several \fakesection{introduction} in my article.
Basically, it will show the "introduction" only in the table of contents and no where else in the article.
The problem is, I don't want the numbering before "introduction" in the table of contents. I only want to show the "introduction".

the popular solutions,   \section*{}  and \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} does not work for \fakesection{}.

Can anyone help me how can I remove the numbering before "introduction" in the table of contents???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.